# How to protect files from outside?

Tags: php, security

I've made a very small CMS myself. After login a session is set.

The CMS includes certain images, php pages, etc.

These pages may also include forms to add data to the database.

Now the problem is that you actually can use an address to get to the page which shows the form, ie;

`domain.com/mycms/includes/addpage.php`

How would you suggest to protect this?

> NOTE: when I am logged in everything must work, just from outside it may not show the form. I could check if the session exists but I wonder if there are better and easier ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, if you are including PHP files, **you really should not place them inside your public web root**.

If this is not possible, an alternative approach would be to **define a constant** in your `index.php` (assuming you use this as a main entry point) and checking wether this constant is set in every include file in order to prevent direct access to these files.

For example:

```
// index.php:
define('INDEX_LOADED', true);

// /includes/addpage.php:
if (!defined('INDEX_LOADED')) die('no direct access allowed');
```

Comment: Files are not in the root. In the root I have a folder named 'mycms'. Inside that folder is another folder named 'includes', this folder contains php files to add data to the database.

I have a login page to get into the cms which includes the php pages  but I can now access them from outside (when I am not logged in).

Comment: @45808 if this is simply a case of not showing stuff to a person that is not logged in, simply do a standard session check before displaying it. There is no 'better' way to do this.

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible for 'outsiders' to see/check which folders/files are on the server?

Comment: @45808 I certainly hope not. Since you asked the question, I really suggest reading some basic tutorials for your webserver configuration (specifically regarding *directory indexes*) and make sure it is at least somewhat safe.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not set up a webserver myself, just using one from an internet provider (bought domain + webspace etc).

Is the function die(); enough to stop people that are not logged in if the session does not exist?

Comment: @45808 why not to use approach like index.php?controller=addpage where controller checking for user rights and including certain files if permission granted?

Comment: That already is the case. Everything works through an index.php file. If the session exists, it includes a php page.

Although it was possible to still get to that page when using the full path. It's fixed now with a session check.

Answer (score 1):

Aim to put your files in

domain.com/**private**/includes/addpage.php

And then from your page do
 something like

include('../private/includes/addpage');

Comment: Pages are getting included already, but I can still access them using the full path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

I always use extension  .inc.php for PHP files that should not be accessed from outside. Then I deny that extension to be visible from outside. For apache you can do this in .htaccess file in main directory:

```
<Files ~ "\.inc\.php$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Also if you use some framework or you have a class (or include) directory you can deny access to the whole directory like this (apache):

```
<Location ~ "^/(classes|framework)"
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Other web servers have other ways to forbid files. If you want it universal and portable - the Aron Rotteveel's suggestion is the best.

You can leave files that only contain classes declarations unprotected - if they are run from outside no code will run. Make sure that php ini setting **display_errors** is **off** for the host

Answer (score 0):

If it necessary to keep private files inside public folder you can protect it with CHMOD  permissions like 700

Comment: since the web user is probably the owner of those files, changing the chmod would not actually result in much more security. The basic setup of having PHP files in the webroot is flawed; changed file permissions cannot really solve this.

Comment: I did not understood your statement, how can you access folder which you are not permitted? I'm not trying to claim that my solution is better than yours, it's just extra measure that can be used to tighten security of web application.

Comment: @Nazarly, the folder *should* actually be permissable for the web server. The client that tries to query for the folder still proxies through the web server, so file and folder permissions don't make that much of a difference in this case.